# getResources().getColor not working in custom View

Tags: java, android, colors, custom-view, getresource

I've made a custom view and can't seem to access my custom defined colors from there. My entire app is comprised of the following 3 files

colors.xml located in res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

TestView.java:

```
public class TestView extends View {

    Paint background;
    int viewWidth;
    int viewHeight;

    public TestView(Context context){
        super(context);
        background = new Paint();
        background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        //find view dimensions
        viewWidth = getWidth();
        viewHeight = getHeight();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,viewWidth,viewHeight, background);      
    }
}
```

and MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    TestView testView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        testView = new TestView(this);
        setContentView(testView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

All I get is a blank white screen, which should be black! I've been trying to figure out what could possibly be causing this for about 2 days straight now, and needless to say I've tried a lot that didn't work. I'd be quite grateful if anyone could help me out with this.

Thanks!

Comment: mispell should be R.colors.black instead of R.color.black

Comment: Hey Hoan Nguyen. It doesn't compile if I write R.colors.black, and yes, the name of the xml is colors.xml. This is one of the things I had already tried, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Does the gen folder contains R.colors.black id?

Comment: Hey Hoan. Yes, I had checked that already, it contained some value like 0x04f0000 or something. Btw, I just figured this out and posted the answer, but thanks for looking into this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.black));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. The problem is that I am setting `viewWidth` and `viewHeight` in the constructor. When I just called `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` directly in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` it worked. I'm guessing that these values have not been set until the `onDraw` method, or at least until after the constructor.

Thanks to Hoan Nguyen for helping out!